# $watch-ing variables across multiple scopes

Tags: angularjs

I'm in a directive, and I would like to do a union `$watch` on a variable that exists on the local `$scope` and one that exists on `$rootScope`. It would look something like:

```
myapp.directive('cohnbread',
            ['TEMPLATE_URL', '$rootScope',
    function(TEMPLATE_URL,    $rootScope) {
        return {
            templateUrl: TEMPLATE_URL + "cohnbread.html",
            scope: { odp: '@' },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                // here I would like to register a callback to fire 
                // whenever scope.bar or $rootScope.foo fires. Something like:
                $watchBoth('scope.bar', '$rootScope.foo', onBarOrFooChange);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Is there a workaround to make this happen?

*Edited to provide more info.*

Comment: What are you trying to do in the $watch? Where are you setting the $watch up? A service that carries the $watch callback as a function may work... but you didn't really give us enough information to answer the question (Unless someone is a lucky guesser).

Comment: can I ask why you have 2 variables with the same name and why are both in need of watching? If they actually have separate purposes then name them accordingly, if not you should only care about the more specific scope variable

Comment: @LiviuT., they don't have the same name. They are separate variables in separate scopes.

Comment: right, didn't see that. Remember that angular scopes use prototype inheritence so watching a variable on the scope will watch it on the rootScope if it doesn't find it on the current scope.

Comment: @LiviuT. in this case, `scope` is isolated, so prototypical inheritance isn't an option. (OP updated to reflect that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to fire a callback when one *or* the other changes, just setup a `$watch` for each one. For example:

```
scope.$watch('bar', onBarOrFooChange);
scope.$watch('foo', onBarOrFooChange);
```

or if your directive has an isolated scope, you could setup the `$watch` for `foo` like this:

```
scope.$watch(function() {return $rootScope.foo}, onBarOrFooChange);
```